# Extract integer from the end of a string

Tags: c#, string, list

I have multiple IDs in a `List<string>()`

```
List<string> IDList = new List<string>() {
"ID101",     //101
"I2D102",    //102
"103",       //103
"I124D104",  //104
"ID-105",    //105
"-1006" };   //1006
```

Rule: The string always ends with the id which has length 1 to n  and is `int` only

I need to extract them to `int` values. But my solution doesn't work

```
List<int> intList = IDList.Select(x => int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @".*\d*").Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: "my solution doesn't work", What does it do that you don't expect? What is it you're trying to retrieve? the last numbers?

Comment: Do you want to *ignore* minus sign? E.g. should `"-1006"` be converted into `1006`?

Comment: Is the ID always at the end?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes only positive, Ian yes

Comment: Then you may consider `LINQ` solution `TakeWhile(x => char.IsNumber(x))` instead of `Regex` too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another LINQ approach which works if the number is always at the end and negative values aren't possible. Skips invalid strings:

```
 List<int> intList = IDList
    .Select(s => s.Reverse().TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit))
    .Where(digits => digits.Any())
    .Select(digits => int.Parse(String.Concat(digits.Reverse())))
    .ToList();
```

( Edit: similar to [Ian's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37205117/284240) )

Answer (score 4):

If ID is always at the end, you could use `LINQ` solution instead of `Regex`:

```
var query = IDList.Select(id => 
    int.Parse(new string(id.Reverse()
        .TakeWhile(x => char.IsNumber(x))
        .Reverse().ToArray())));
```

The idea is to take the characters from the last till it finds no number. Whatever you get, you convert it into `int`. The good thing about this solution is it really represents what you specify.

Answer (score 4):

Well, according to

> Rule: The string always ends with the id which has length 1 to n and
>   is int only

the pattern is nothing but

```
  [0-9]{1,n}$

  [0-9] - ints only 
  {1,n} - from 1 to n (both 1 and n are included)
  $     - string always ends with
```

and possible implementation could be something like this

```
  int n = 5; //TODO: put actual value
  String pattern = "[0-9]{1," + n.ToString() + "}$";

  List<int> intList = IDList
    .Select(line => int.Parse(Regex.Match(line, pattern).Value))
    .ToList();
```

In case there're some *broken lines*, say `"abc"` (and you want to *filter them out*):

```
  List<int> intList = IDList
    .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern))
    .Where(match => match.Success)
    .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This below code extract last id as integer from collection and ignore them which end with none integer value

```
List<int> intList = IDList.Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a, @"\d+$") == true)
   .Select(x => int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+$").Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: is there a way to prevent a exception in case of invalid id? e.g. "abc" to ignore this one in the result list?

Comment: yes you can ignore them using my updated code ,if end value are not a valid int then it ignore them, try my latest update

Answer (score -2):

i assume you want the last numbers :

```
var res = IDList.Select(x => int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+$").Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: what is different with my solution ?

Comment: It's just a copy of the above solution.

Comment: Sorry, when i post my solution, you already post yours. i should have make F5 before post mine.